# Kalman Filter Covariance and Gains "Copied"

Tags: kalman-filter

It has been a couple years since I last touched on Kalman filtering and I have been approached with a design implementation that I am uncertain of so I figure I would ask here...

The design is for tracking multiple balls in space. We define their system as the standard second order equation x+v*t+a*t^2. Now let us assume that each ball is thrown from a pitching machine. While the pitching machine should be constant we cannot definitively make that assumption... With this in mind the question that I have is: If we have 2 balls in our space that we are tracking, separated by 10 sampling intervals. Assuming that each balls initial position, velocity, and acceleration are the same can we essentially "prime" the filter gains for ball 2 with that of ball 1's values? I.e. Can we use ball 1's filter gain and covariance matrices to reduce our estimation error on ball 2 from the start instead of letting the transients resolve naturally? The goal of this would be to essentially 'train' our Kalman filter for each ball moving forward to better make a better estimator.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally a ball thrown by a pitching machine follows a path that's entirely determined by the initial conditions.  What you seem to be describing is one filter to track the ball's position (which should be using a prediction function for an ideal trajectory, not a random jerk model), and another "meta" filter which is modelling the parameters of the pitching machine.

So your frame-by-frame tracking would update a filter that models the initial conditions times time plus some offset model for error from ideal.  The results of each pitch would be a final estimate of initial conditions which would be one "sample" for the meta-filter about the machine.  The meta-filter would provide initial conditions for the next ball tracking filter.

You could definitely mush all this together into one filter (resetting the per-ball components on each pitch) but I don't see any real advantages.